# After creating relationships on model object, I am not getting the newly added relationships instances from the object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a one-to-many realtionship between `$task` and `$moment`. So many moments belong to task.

On edit of task, I am adding moments like this:

api.php implicit:

```
Route::put('tasks/{task}', 'PetController@updateTask');

public function updateTask(Request $request, Task $task) {

    foreach ($request->moments as $requestMoment) {
        $task->moments()->create($requestMoment);
    }

    $task->fresh();

    foreach($task->moments as $moment) {
         // logging out $moment
    }
}
```

When I do that second `foreach` it is not finding the newly created moment. I even did a `$task->fresh()` before iterating the second time, but its still not finding the newly created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) To load a relationship only when it has not already been loaded, use the `loadMissing` method:

```
public function updateTask(Request $request, Task $task) {

        foreach ($request->moments as $requestMoment) {
            $task->moments()->create($requestMoment);
        }

        $task->loadMissing('moments');

        foreach($task->moments as $moment) {
             // logging out $moment
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahdi! That fixed it I have no idea why. How come `->fresh()` didnt work?

Comment: `fresh()` only   reloads a fresh model instance from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$task->with('moments')->fresh()` to include the relations.

or `$task->load('moments')` one of those should work.

Comment: Thanks very much @btl that fixed it too! Thanks for showing the alternatives! I don't understand the `fresh` too much, how come doing `$task->fresh()` didnt fresh it up?

Comment: `$task->fresh()` was only getting the task's attributes. These actually reload all the related models as well.